# pin-to-pin pitch of krc-86b

Tags: pcb-design

What is the pin-to-pin pitch of the KRC-86B Bluetooth module?  All I know is it is smaller than the standard 2.54mm pitch.

I am trying to find a JST connector that will fit properly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this not specified in the module's datasheet?

Comment: Not that I was able to find but Spehro was able to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pitch is 2.0mm, according to [this](https://yourmestudio.en.alibaba.com/product/60101060552-221034612/KRC_86B_module_Bluetooth_4_0_stereo_audio_receiver_module.html) site.

[image]